# Creating a TreeMultimap with Immutable object

Tags: java, guava, immutables-library

I am currently using [immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) to construct concrete objects.
I am facing an issue while trying to create a `TreeMultiMap`.

ERROR: It is expecting a comparable in the `OrderKey` to create the map,
How do I set the comparator with immutables to create a `TreeMultiMap`?

```
//Does not compile here
SortedSetMultimap<ImmutableOrderKey, ImmutableOrder > orderMap= TreeMultimap.create();


@Value.Immutable
interface OrderKey {
    long orderNum();
}


@Value.Immutable
  interface Order {
  long orderNum();
  DateTime orderDate();
  String deliveryAddress();
}
```

Comment: A **sorted** map implies using some sort of order for its keys. You need to specify what order that is supposed to be.

Comment: Agreed, how do I specify this when I use Immutables? How do I specify that my OrderKey should use a certain comparator. The equals and hashcode methods are implemented within the ImmutableOrderKey class.

Comment: I don't see why the fact that it is immutable would be relevant. Write a `Comparator`. There are lots of resources that describe how to do that.

Comment: Are you looking for https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html#create(java.util.Comparator,%20java.util.Comparator)?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make sure that your Immutable objects implement the `Comparable` interface.

If you're using Java 8, this can be achieved using default methods:

```
@Value.Immutable
interface OrderKey extends Comparable<OrderKey> {
    long orderNum();

    default int compareTo(OrderKey o) {
        return orderNum() - o.orderNum();
    }
}
```

If you're pre-java 8, consider using abstract classes instead of interfaces to achieve the same effect.

---

Another approach (again java 8) is to supply comparators to the the creation method, e.g.:

```
Comparator<OrderKey> orderKeyCmp = Comparator.comparingLong(OrderKey::orderNum);
Comparator<Order> orderCmp = Comparator.comparing(Order::orderDate);

SortedSetMultimap<ImmutableOrderKey, ImmutableOrder> orderMap 
    = TreeMultimap.create(orderKeyCmp, orderCmp);
```

The above will sort `OrderKey` instances according to the `orderNum` field, and `Order` instances according to the `orderDate` field.